# Creating a space between figure number and label in latex table of figures

Tags: latex

Hi I have a problem with the table of figures in latex. As the figure below shows, the figure number is quite long and bleeding over the figure label. Any ideas on how I can address this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A workaround: Use horizontal space in the short caption argument of your figure environment

```
\caption[\hspace{0.5cm} short caption text]{Long caption text}
```

This is of course not a too nice solution, though. If you want to avoid it, you would have to fudge the code in your document class, I believe.

Comment: @Werner: Thanks for your valuable comment. My answer is marked to be a workaround/not too nice, but it works. Feel free to answer with richer content, that's how SO works

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) to define the spacing between the figure number and figure caption within the LoF. The length that controls this distance is `\cftfignumwidth`. Here's a quick example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{3em}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
  \caption[short caption text]{Long caption text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The above suggestion provides a consistent adjustment that can be changed as needed.

Reference:

- [List of figures: numbers overlap image caption](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/87019/5764)
- [How to modify the space between the numbers and text of sectioning titles in the table of contents?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/33841/5764)

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error like:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \c@lofdepth already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

Try using tocloft from the **subfigure** package:

```
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}

\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{4em}
```